# Populate input after change on a select

Tags: jquery

Following the following table, how I can populate the row input on select change ?

I have several rows as the  one.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="60%">Date</th>
            <th width="40%">Rate</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Today<br><select name="RAT_Rates" class="form-control"><option data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Custom</option><option data-name="Special" data-description="Special" data-rate="99.99"> Special - $ 99.99</option></select></th>
            <td>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Tomorrow<br><select name="RAT_Rates" class="form-control"><option data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Custom</option><option data-name="Special" data-description="Special" data-rate="99.99"> Special - $ 99.99</option></select></th>
            <td>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've actually:

```
$('select[name=RAT_Rates]').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

    var name = selected.attr('data-name');
    var description = selected.attr('data-description');
    var rate = selected.attr('data-rate');

    $(this).next('input[name=BIL_Rate]').val(rate);
});
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `name` attribute of the `input` tag is "BIL_Rate[]". What's with the brackets?

Comment: Cause the final result should be treat like an array. I have several row like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the attribute selector, you need to use the two sets of quotes.
One set for the selector itself...
And one for the attribute's value you look for.

So `$('select[name=RAT_Rates]')` should be `$("select[name='RAT_Rates']")`.

Then *(this is minor, but valid HTML always helps)*, your `select` element was not closed.

```js
$("select[name='RAT_Rates']").on('change', function() {

  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

  var name = selected.attr('data-name');
  var description = selected.attr('data-description');
  var rate = selected.attr('data-rate');

  $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='BIL_Rate[]']").val(rate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="60%">Date</th>
      <th width="40%">Rate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Today<br>
        <select name="RAT_Rates" class="form-control">
          <option data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Custom</option>
          <option data-name="Special" data-description="Special" data-rate="99.99"> Special - $ 99.99</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello, your solution works bu except if I only one row which is unfortunately not my case. I have several rows like this, so your code once the select changes, fill all other inputs with the value. I need only the one on the same row. Sorry if it was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parent() and locate the class inside using find(). Check my update code below:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th width="60%">Date</th>
        <th width="40%">Rate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Today<br><select name="RAT_Rates" class="form-control"><option data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Custom</option><option data-name="Special" data-description="Special" data-rate="99.99"> Special - $ 99.99</option></select></th>
        <td>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]"  class="form-control input_rate" required="">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Today<br><select name="RAT_Rates" class="form-control"><option data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Custom</option><option data-name="Special" data-description="Special" data-rate="99.99"> Special - $ 99.99</option></select></th>
        <td>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]"  class="form-control input_rate" required="">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Today<br><select name="RAT_Rates" class="form-control"><option data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Custom</option><option data-name="Special" data-description="Special" data-rate="99.99"> Special - $ 99.99</option></select></th>
        <td>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]"  class="form-control input_rate" required="">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Javascript :**

```
 $('select[name=RAT_Rates]').on('change', function() {
var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

var name = selected.attr('data-name');
var description = selected.attr('data-description');
var rate = selected.attr('data-rate');

$(this).parent().parent().find('.input_rate').val(rate);
});
```

Comment: Hello, as I have several row like in my question, I can't use your solution right now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

here is what you want -

```js
$('select[name=RAT_Rates]').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

    var name = selected.attr('data-name');
    var description = selected.attr('data-description');
    var rate = selected.attr('data-rate');
    $(this).closest('td').next('td').find($("input[name='BIL_Rate[]']")).val(rate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="60%">Date</th>
            <th width="40%">Rate</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <div>
            Today
            </div> 
              <select name="RAT_Rates" class="form-control">
              <option data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Custom</option>
              <option data-name="Special" data-description="Special" data-rate="99.99"> Special - $ 99.99</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><div>
         Tomorrow
         </div>
            <select name="RAT_Rates" class="form-control"><option data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Custom</option><option data-name="Special" data-description="Special" data-rate="99.99"> Special - $ 99.99</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: I have several row like the one mentions in my question. I think your code will fill all my input no?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question as it was unclear at the beginning. Sorry.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope you are looking for this only.
I have made some small changes to your html as well. Thanks